# C - How to send signal from a child process to another one?

Tags: c, operating-system, pipe, signals, ipc

I'm trying to do this exercise with pipes for my OS class: say we have N child processes. I need to send a SIGUSR1 from a single process to another one that has `i=N/2`.

Example:

There are 4 child processes:

```
P1=100    i=0

P2=101    i=1

P3=102    i=2

P4=103    i=3
```

In this case,`P1` should sends a SIGUSR1 to `P3`, since `P1 i=i+N/2=0+4/2=2`, `P2` should sends a SIGUSR1 to `P4`, since `P2 i=i+N/2=1+4/2=3`.

And this is what I've done so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

#define SIZE 1024

void myhandler(int signum);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])

{

int n, i=0, i_p;
int nread;
pid_t childpid, pid;

char buffer[SIZE];
char str[25];


   srand(time(NULL));

   do{
   n=(rand()%5)*2;
   }while(n==0);

int choice=n/2;

int *fds=malloc(2*n*sizeof*fds);

    for(i=0; i<n; ++i) {
        pipe(&fds[i*2]);} 

signal(SIGUSR1, myhandler);

childpid=fork();
if(childpid>0)
  for(i=1; i<n; i++)
     {
      sleep(1);
      childpid=fork();
      if(childpid==0)
        break;
     }
    if(childpid==0)
     {
     close(fds[i*0]);
     pid=getpid();
     sprintf(buffer, "%d", pid);    
     write(fds[i*1], buffer, strlen(buffer)+1);
     close(fds[i*1]);
     }

 i_p=i+choice;
    if(i<choice)
       {
        close(fds[i_p*1]);
        nread=read(fds[i_p*0], buffer, SIZE);
        close(fds[i_p*0]);
        pid=atoi(buffer);
        if(i_p<n)
             kill(pid, SIGUSR1);
        }

            else if(i_p>n)
                fprintf(stderr, "%d: can't send signal.\n", getpid());

  fprintf(stderr, "Parent: %d   child: %d   %d\n", getppid(), getpid(), i);
   sleep(1); 
      }

void myhandler(int signum)

{
   if(signum==SIGUSR1)
    {
     fprintf(stderr, "\n");
     fprintf(stderr, "Process %d: SIGUSR1 received.\n", getpid());
    }
}
```

But the output is different than expected and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: `i*0` and `i*1` look quite strange. I think you mean something else.

Comment: Well, since I created dynamically an array of pipes for each child process, I used this notation in order to access the pipes from more processes but I don't know if it is correct.